# Dictionary of terms index and posting list compression

Tags: nlp, nltk, tokenize, information-retrieval, freetext

I'm studying and developing a simple information retrieval system base on the book ["Introduction to information retrieval"](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/information-retrieval-book.html) and there are two topic about the dictionary and posting list compression that I'm not understanding very well.

In the [chapter 5](https://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/pdf/05comp.pdf) of the book some techniques about the compression of the dictionary and posting list are explained:

- blocked compression {eg. "This is an example" -> "4this2is2an7example"} *not considering stop words.
- in the posting list then there will be, for each term:    (in this case the pointer is the position of the k block and then a linear scanner is performed.

[image]

Regarding this consideration I have a question:

- How the compression works? When I compress my dictionary of terms to fit it entire in memory then to perform a query I need to decompress it? And what if the decompressed dictionary is not able to be fitted in memory?
- How the posting list compression works? In my case my posting list in formed by different terms: [document_frequency doc_id:document_frequency_in_doc_id ...]. In the book some technique (gamma compression) for compressing the doc_id are explained but what about other useful information to perform ranking retrieval? For example the frequency of the term in the document or the position of the term.